# How to use Angular Material Component mat-form-field in JHipster Project

Tags: angular-material, jhipster

JHipster project is created and we are using visual code editor for accessing angular components. For using angular material components we installed them using command npm install --save @angular/material.

We try to import angular material using

```
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';   
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        LayoutRoutingModule,
        Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-'}),
        // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
        MatFormFieldModule
    ]
```

in app.module.ts

On compiling we are getting error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/expansion.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/accordion' in 'E:\Mrudula\Work\GitBlit_Project\OFPL\
node_modules\@angular\material\esm5'
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/expansion.es5.js 11:0-92
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/material.es5.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/a
pp.main
```

Comment: hello, did you managed to solve this issue?? Or generally integrate angular material to jhipster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I installed using the following commands

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

npm install --save @angular/animations
```